# Why my scrollBy doesn't seems to work when I load the page altough it passes trough? Altough the second time into the hashchange it works

Tags: javascript

When I add this question yesterday, there was a problem after minifying that didn't have anything to do with my question. So I solved that problem and now you can see the real problem described here unther. Thankyou very much to have a look. You can test it on the website, which is a small student project: https://21-team-813.netlify.app/

I try to make a javascript to uncover my titles that went unther the navbar when I go to an ID titel with the dropdown menu. It works perfect with 'hashchange'-eventListener where I use the scrollBy in the function of y pixels to scroll down. But because of the first time when you load the page there is no 'hashchange'-event so on pageload I also pass through exactly the same scrollBy. But for some reason, that first time it never works. Altough it has the height of the navbar loaded and he passes the function I added with the scrollBy to see if it passes there. So, do you have any idea why the first time after page load it does not work? For example if you come from HOME and choose the second dropdown menu of Ecovacs menu. After that it works fine. Thankyou very much.

Code:

```
const navbar = document.querySelector('nav.navbar');
//load the first title above the page since it cannot scroll and I have to add padding
const beschrijving = document.getElementById('beschrijving');
navbarHoogte = navbar.offsetHeight;
beschrijving.style.paddingTop = `${navbarHoogte}px`;
scrol();
function scrol() {
    console.log('check if we pass into the function');
    window.scrollBy(0, -navbarHoogte);
    console.log('function should have been executed');
}
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () {
    navbarHoogte = navbar.offsetHeight;
    beschrijving.style.paddingTop = `${navbarHoogte}px`;
    window.scrollBy(0, -navbarHoogte);
});
```

Comment: Probably the DOM is not ready when the script is executed. Where do you put/load the script?

Comment: @SvenEberth at the bottom I load the scripts. You can see the site (studentproject) at https://21-team-813.netlify.app/   From home you go to the Ecovacs menu and choose in the dropdown "Instellingen APP" .Thankyou anyway

Comment: Take a look in the developer console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'o' has already been declared`.
Your two minified scripts (student1_carousel_control.js and student1-move-anchor-downnavbar.js) use the same constant `o`. The second one tries to redeclare the value which is forbidden. So your script is not executed (you will not see the `console.log`s as well).

Comment: @SvenEberth sorry, I see now that the online version has this problem and therefore nothing works. But the strange thing is that on my local version I don't have that error and it works a lot better, apart from that one situation. The minifieing I don't have control of, that is a script of the school who does the minify thing. So how can I prevent that my local stuff is minified like this to become two same variabels? Thankyou for showing me that extra problem anyway, since I tested mainly local.

Comment: You can put your scripts in separate namespaces: Wrap them by `(function() { /* your code */ })();`. Or put all scripts together and minify them once.

Comment: @SvenEberth thankyou that you mentioned yesterday that problem online, I putted the 2 files together.
The real question is why if I go from HOME to a dropdown menu of the menu ECOVACS that the first time the navbar covers my title, altough the script goes trough the scrollBY and the next times when it goes trough the eventListener hashchange, then the same line does his work and the titles appear beautifully below the navbar. I don't understand why the first time it won't work since I putted the code also above the eventlistener. And it passes there because it shows the height of my navbar.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your second click is that the location-hash will not change and your eventHandler will not be triggered. But the default behavior for anchor-links taskes action (jump to the section with id, so that the section will be at the top of your window).

I think to use here a click-handler would work better.

```js
const navbarHoogte = document.querySelector('nav.navbar').offsetHeight;
document.querySelectorAll('a.dropdown-item').forEach(item => 
    item.addEventListener('click', e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let section = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.href.split('#')[1]);
        window.scrollBy(0, section.getBoundingClientRect().top - navbarHoogte);
    })
);
```

Comment: Seems a good idea and yesterday I tried as well with a click event on the dropdowns. Today after your post I tried again but for some reason it doesn't work. I don't know why. Thanks for the effort... Only one thing.... you put section.getBounding... which section? I putted there the a.dropdown-item since I didn't know what you meant with section? Anyway thanks for the effort. I appreciate that.

Comment: The sections in your html, like `<section id="instellingen">`

Comment: Yes I thought so. I am going to have a look at it again tomorrow. Thankyou very much